# ADO retrievable data service?

Tags: ado, recordset

Need pointers on how to make a data provider/service ADO-compatible. This requirement is quite similar to how we use classic ado to query an LDAP server (active directory). Here is an e.g. of the same --> http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041800-1.shtm

However the stuff I am expecting this provider would do is, actually talk to a WCF service underneath, and somehow generate a recordset for downstream consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make the data  you are extracting available via an ADO interface, you might take a look at the article here - its a bit dated, but I suspect the basic concepts are still valid.

[ADO Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301611.aspx)